# Помоги решить проблему с сервером майнкрафта

Tags: ubuntu, сервер, minecraft

У меня есть такая проблема что на моем сервере личном через некоторое время перестал запускаться сервер. Показывает вот эту ошибку

````
[20:39:39] [Server thread/INFO]: Loading properties
[20:39:40] [Server thread/INFO]: Default game type: SURVIVAL
[20:39:40] [Server thread/INFO]: Generating keypair
[20:39:40] [Server thread/INFO]: Starting Minecraft server on *:25565
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0 (file:/home/minecraft/minecraft_server.jar) to field java.nio.Buffer.address
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
Aug 04, 2021 8:39:40 PM io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent <clinit>
INFO: Your platform does not provide complete low-level API for accessing direct buffers reliably. Unless explicitly requested, heap buffer will always be preferred to avoid potential system unstability.
[20:39:40] [Server thread/INFO]: Using epoll channel type
[20:39:40] [Server thread/INFO]: Preparing level "world"
java.io.FileNotFoundException: ./world/session.lock (Permission denied)
at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:298)
at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:237)
at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:187)
at azy.i(SourceFile:56)
at azy.<init>(SourceFile:50)
at azv.<init>(SourceFile:21)
at azw.a(SourceFile:83)
at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.a(SourceFile:242)
at ld.j(SourceFile:228)
at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.run(SourceFile:428)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
[20:39:40] [Server thread/ERROR]: Encountered an unexpected exception
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to check session lock, aborting
at azy.i(SourceFile:64) ~[minecraft_server.jar:?]
at azy.<init>(SourceFile:50) ~[minecraft_server.jar:?]
at azv.<init>(SourceFile:21) ~[minecraft_server.jar:?]
at azw.a(SourceFile:83) ~[minecraft_server.jar:?]
at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.a(SourceFile:242) ~[minecraft_server.jar:?]
at ld.j(SourceFile:228) ~[minecraft_server.jar:?]
at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.run(SourceFile:428) [minecraft_server.jar:?]
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) [?:?]
[20:39:40] [Server thread/ERROR]: This crash report has been saved to: /home/minecraft/./crash-reports/crash-2021-08-04_20.39.40-server.txt
[20:39:40] [Server thread/INFO]: Stopping server
[20:39:40] [Server thread/INFO]: Saving players
[20:39:40] [Server thread/INFO]: Saving worlds
[20:39:40] [Server Shutdown Thread/INFO]: Stopping server
[20:39:40] [Server Shutdown Thread/INFO]: Saving players
[20:39:40] [Server Shutdown Thread/INFO]: Saving worlds```
````

Comment: Файл './world/session.lock', на который ругается, есть на месте? Если есть, то , похоже, у вас запущен второй процесс, который, вероятно, не остановился как полагается или завис. Проверьте командой `ps uax | grep server.jar | grep -v grep`. Если же файла нет, то похоже у вас повреждены файлы мира. Бекап есть?

Comment: Бекапов не делал, а из-за чего может вообще был произойди краш ?

Comment: И можно будет как-то это иправить без бекапов, просто это мой первый опыт в создании сервере на сервере и я ничего не знал

Comment: Начиная от ошибок в софте и сбоя железа, до [космической радиации](https://habr.com/ru/post/401681/) (это не шутка, в Бельгии [это привело](https://www.wnycstudios.org/podcasts/radiolab/articles/bit-flip) в искажению результатов выборов). Попробовать восстановить можно. Я бы сначала сделал бекап того, что есть. Потом посмотрел на разницу в файлах в папке world текущей и сгенерированной с нуля. Возможно, если не хватает только session.lock, то достаточно будет его скопировать из нового мира. Но нужно экспериментировать.

Comment: Ну и если вы ожидаете помощи, то не игнорируйте заданные вам вопросы. Без этого помочь будет трудно ;)

Comment: Я буду утром уже разбираться с этим, спасибо за вашу помощь